# node-canvas registerFont can't find font file once deployed (works locally)

Tags: node.js, fonts, vercel, node-canvas

I have a Node.js server that uses node-canvas to render text on an image on the server-side. Here is the repo: https://github.com/shawninder/meme-generator (just `git clone`, `npm i` and `npm run dev` to run locally).

As you'll notice in the code, I am loading the *Anton* font, which I got from [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Anton?query=Anton&selection.family=Anton&sidebar.open) with the documented `registerFont` function provided by node-canvas

```js
registerFont('./fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf', { family: 'Anton' })
```

Everything works like a charm locally, but when I deploy to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/home) (formerly known as zeit), that line throws an `ENOENT` error:

> no such file or directory, lstat '/var/task/fonts'

- Is there a path I can use here that will successfully load the font from within a Vercel function?
- Can I find a single path that will work both locally and once deployed?

Comment: If it helps, this is the repo I am working on: https://github.com/shawninder/meme-generator . If you clone it, `npm install` and `npm run dev`, you'll get a simple meme generator where you can put some text over an image. Although far from finished, it does work. However, once deployed to "now", the fonts don't work (see https://meme-generator-jet.now.sh/). This is precisely my issue so feel free to get your hands on that repo and try things out for yourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being

```
import path from 'path'
registerFont(path.resolve('./fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf'), { family: 'Anton' })`
```

See [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Comment: Still not sure why `path.resolve` didn't work the first time I tried it, maybe there was something else wrong at that time...

Comment: This didn't work for me at all (which is why I added my answer), did this work for anyone else?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently and I finally found a solution. I'm no guru, so someone will probably be able to suggest a better way, but here's what worked for me.

Because of how Vercel runs their serverless functions, a function doesn't really know anything about the rest of the project, or the public folder. This makes sense (because security), but it does make it tricky when you need the actual path to a file. You can import the font file no problem, the build process will give it a new name and put it on the disk (in `/var/task` ), but you can't access it. `path.resolve(_font_name_)` can see it, but you can't access it.

I ended up writing a very bad, separate api page that used `path.join` and `fs.readdirSync` to see what files are actually visible from the api page. One thing that is visible is a node_modules folder that contains the files for modules used on that api page.

```
fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/')
```

So what I did was write a local module, install it in my project, then import it into my api page. In the local module's `package.json`, I have a line `"files": ["*"]` so it will bundle all the module files into its node_modules folder (instead of just the .js files). In my module I have my font file and a function that copies it to `/tmp` (`/tmp` is readable and writable) then returns the path to the file, `/tmp/Roboto-Regular.ttf`.

On my api page, I include this module, then run it, and I pass the resultant path to `registerfont`.

It works. I'd share my code, but it's pretty sloppy right now, and I'd like to clean it up and try a couple things first (like I'm not sure if I need to copy it to /tmp, but I haven't tested it without that step). When I get it straightened out I'll edit this answer.

-- EDIT
Since I haven't been able to improve on my original solution, let me give some more details about what I did.

In my package.json I added a line to include a local module:

```
"dependencies": {
 "canvas": "^2.6.1",
 "fonttrick": "file:fonttrick",
```

In my project root, I have a folder "fonttrick". Inside the folder is another package.json:

```
{
    "name": "fonttrick",
    "version": "1.0.6",
    "description": "a trick to get canvas registerfont to work in a Vercel serverless function",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://grumbly.games",
    "main": "index.js",
    "files": [
        "*"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "registerfont",
        "canvas",
        "vercel",
        "zeit",
        "nextjs"
    ]
}
```

This is the only local module I've ever had to write; the keywords don't do anything, but at first I'd thought about putting it on NPM, so they're there.

The fonttrick folder also contains my font file (in this case "Roboto-Regular.ttf"), and a the main file, *index.js*:

```
module.exports = function fonttrick() {
  const fs = require('fs')
  const path = require('path')
  const RobotoR = require.resolve('./Roboto-Regular.ttf')
  const { COPYFILE_EXCL } = fs.constants;
  const { COPYFILE_FICLONE } = fs.constants;

  //const pathToRoboto = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/fonttrick/Roboto-Regular.ttf')

  try {
    if (fs.existsSync('/tmp/Roboto-Regular.ttf')) {
      console.log("Roboto lives in tmp!!!!")
    } else {
      fs.copyFileSync(RobotoR, '/tmp/Roboto-Regular.ttf', COPYFILE_FICLONE | COPYFILE_EXCL)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  return '/tmp/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
};
```

I ran *npm install* in this folder, and then fonttrick was available as a module in my main project (don't forget to run *npm install* there, too).

Since I only need to use this for API calls, the module is only used in one file, */pages/api/[img].js*

```
import { drawCanvas } from "../../components/drawCanvas"
import { stringIsValid, strToGameState } from '../../components/gameStatePack'
import fonttrick from 'fonttrick'


export default (req, res) => {      // { query: { img } }
  // some constants
  const fallbackString = "1xThe~2ysent~3zlink~4yis~5wnot~6xa~7xvalid~8zsentence~9f~~"
  // const fbs64 = Buffer.from(fallbackString,'utf8').toString('base64')

  // some variables
  let imageWidth = 1200     // standard for fb ogimage
  let imageHeight = 628     // standard for fb ogimage

  // we need to remove the initial "/api/" before we can use the req string
  const reqString64 = req.url.split('/')[2]
  // and also it's base64 encoded, so convert to utf8
  const reqString = Buffer.from(reqString64, 'base64').toString('utf8')

  //const pathToRoboto = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/fonttrick/Roboto-Regular.ttf')
  let output = null

  if (stringIsValid({ sentenceString: reqString })) {
    let data = JSON.parse(strToGameState({ canvasURLstring: reqString }))
    output = drawCanvas({
      sentence: data.sentence,
      cards: data.cards,
      width: imageWidth,
      height: imageHeight,
      fontPath: fonttrick()
    })
  } else {
    let data = JSON.parse(strToGameState({ canvasURLstring: fallbackString }))
    output = drawCanvas({
      sentence: data.sentence,
      cards: data.cards,
      width: imageWidth,
      height: imageHeight,
      fontPath: fonttrick()
    })
  }

  const buffy = Buffer.from(output.split(',')[1], 'base64')
  res.statusCode = 200
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
  res.end(buffy)
}
```

The important part of what this does is **import fonttrick** which puts a copy of the font in tmp, then returns the path to that file; **the path to the font is then passed to the canvas drawing function** (along with some other stuff; what to draw, how big to draw it, etc.)

My drawing function itself is in *components/drawCanvas.js*; here's the important stuff at the beginning (**TLDR** version: if it gets called from the API page, it gets a path to the font; if so, it uses that, otherwise the regular system fonts are available):

```
import { registerFont, createCanvas } from 'canvas';
import path from 'path'


// width and height are optional
export const drawCanvas = ({ sentence, cards, width, height, fontPath }) => {
  // default canvas size
  let cw = 1200 // canvas width
  let ch = 628 // canvas height
  // if given different canvas size, update
  if (width && !height) {
    cw = width
    ch = Math.floor(width / 1.91)
  }
  if (height && width) {
    cw = width
    ch = height
  }
  if (height && !width) {
    ch = height
    cw = Math.floor(height * 1.91)
  }

  // this path is only used for api calls in development mode
  let theFontPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf')
  // when run in browser, registerfont isn't available,
  // but we don't need it; when run from an API call,
  // there is no css loaded, so we can't get fonts from @fontface
  // and the canvas element has no fonts installed by default;
  // in dev mode we can load them from local, but when run serverless
  // it gets complicated: basically, we have a local module whose only
  // job is to get loaded and piggyback the font file into the serverless
  // function (thread); the module default function copies the font to
  // /tmp then returns its absolute path; the function in the api 
  // then passes that path here so we can load the font from it  
  if (registerFont !== undefined) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      theFontPath = fontPath
    }
    registerFont(theFontPath, { family: 'Roboto' })
  }
  const canvas = createCanvas(cw, ch)
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
```

This API path gets used in the header for my game, in the meta tags to create the image on demand when a page gets shared on facebook or twitter or wherever:

```
<meta property="og:image" content={`https://grumbly.games/api/${returnString}`} />
```

Anyway. Ugly and hacky, but it works for me.

Comment: That's great Robert, thanks a lot! I am looking forward to hearing of the results of your experiments! When I get a bit of time to work on this, I will also try your strategy in my context and see if I can make any progress. I can also report back here if I learn anything.

Comment: Any updates on this Robert? I'd be curious to see your working code as I still haven't been able to make this work...

Comment: Hi, I've actually been working on something else and haven't thought about this in a while because I got it working. I did try a few other things but couldn't find any way to improvement it. Will edit my answer with details.

Comment: Wow this is really great, thanks a lot Robert for your time and effort. It is greatly appreciated and I'm sure it will help others too somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were very close with `registerFont`. Here’s what I got to work using your repo:

In `img.js`:

```js
import { registerFont, createCanvas, loadImage } from 'canvas'

// …

// Where 'Anton' is the same font-family name you want to use within
// your canvas code, ie. in writeText.js.
registerFont('./pages/fonts/Anton/Anton-Regular.ttf', { family: 'Anton' })

// Make sure this goes after registerFont()
const canvas = createCanvas()

//…
```

I added a new folder in `pages/` called `fonts/`, and added the Anton folder downloaded from Google Fonts. Click “Download Family” to get the font file from here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Anton?query=Anton&selection.family=Anton&sidebar.open

The other file you downloaded (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap) is actually the CSS file you’ll want to use the fonts client side in the browser, for your previewer.

At first, I would keep using the hosted version provided by Google Fonts. You can add that to the `PreviewMeme.js` component:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet" />
<canvas id='meme' ref={canvas}></canvas>
```

(You might also want to use something like [FontFaceObserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) client side to make sure the font has loaded before rendering your canvas the first time.)

In `writeText.js` you’ll also then change the `fontFamily` to Anton:

```js
const fontFamily = 'Anton'
```

That will make Anton available client side via the hosted Google Fonts, and it should be available to you as a file on the server for rendering with the server-side canvas package.

[image: “Top” “Bottom” sample image output from provided code]

Hope that’s helpful!

Comment: Looks extremely helpful! I will need to find some time to review this and test it out, but if this works I will come back here, accept the answer and award the bounty :) It might be a few days though, sorry

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. If you visit my repo now, you'll notice your suggested changes are in place, and although everything stills works locally, it still does not work once deployed to zeit (now Vercel). Instead, once deployed I now get an Internal Server Error. Did you say you succeeded at this (actually deployed)? Maybe I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like the files actually need to be in the `public/` directory, plus there is still more custom config Next.js requires. This example using the `next-fonts` dependency looks like it will help: https://github.com/rohanray/next-fonts-example

Comment: Tried it, same result. Works locally, not once deployed (Internal Server Error). You can see the updated code in the repo.

Comment: This path shouldn’t have “public” in it: https://github.com/shawninder/meme-generator/commit/d7e38a82a13cf022069f6aad4e79b53adad13525#diff-5c9b440f72d41a969b4eff21bb9349e3R4 That’s removed as part of the deploy: https://meme-generator-jet.now.sh/fonts/

Comment: If I take public out (`registerFont('./fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf', { family: 'Anton' })`) then it doesn't work locally, saying `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/shawn/git/shawninder/meme-generator/fonts'`

Comment: I also tried without the leading dot (`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/fonts'`) just in case but of course that also doesn't work, saying `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/fonts'`

Comment: And finally, I also tried without the leading slash (`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/shawn/git/shawninder/meme-generator/fonts'`) but that fails too, saying `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/shawn/git/shawninder/meme-generator/fonts'`. So that's why I ended up using `public` in there, otherwise nothing works even locally.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up, did you ever get this to work both locally and once deployed to Vercel?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working, using officially-documented configurations rather than the hacky top answer!

First of all, I'm assuming your serverless function is at `api/some_function.js`, where the `api/` folder is at the project root.

1. Create a folder in `api/` to put static files into, such as `api/_files/`. For me, I put font and image files.
2. Put this in `vercel.json`:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "api/some_function.js": {
      "includeFiles": "_files/**"
    }
  }
}
```

3. Now in `api/some_function.js`, you can use `__dirname` to reference the files:

```js
const { join } = require('path')
registerFont(join(__dirname, '_files/fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf'), { family: 'Anton' })
```

This is based on [this Vercel help page](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions), except I had to figure out where the `_files/` folder goes in your project directory structure because they forgot to mention that.